# Calculating Dual-Energy Gradient using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have the definition of "dual-energy gradient" ([Reference](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring13/cos226/assignments/seamCarving.html)) of pixel `(x, y)` is `Δ^2(x, y) + Δy^2(x, y)`, where the square of the x-gradient `Δx^2(x, y) = Rx(x, y)^2 + Gx(x, y)^2 + Bx(x, y)^2` and where the central differences Rx(x, y), Gx(x, y), and Bx(x, y) are the absolute value in differences of red, green, and blue components between pixel (x + 1, y) and pixel (x − 1, y) and similar for y-gradient.

How do I calculate this efficiently using numpy?

I am not sure if the [numpy.gradient](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) can help me out of box.

Comment: What are Rx(x,y) Gx(x,y) Bx(x,y) ? I'm guessing it has something to do with the RGB components of the image but what does the 'x' mean ?

Comment: @ma3oun - updated my definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, if there is a built-in function for your calculation (maybe you want to explore [`scipy.ndimage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html)).
If not, here is a version using only `numpy` functions:

```
import numpy as np

#convert from uint8 to int64 to prevent overflow problems
arr = np.array(loaded_pic, dtype = int)
#calculate squared difference ((x-1, y) - (x+1, y))^2 for each R, G and B pixel
deltaX2 = np.square(np.roll(arr, -1, axis = 0) - np.roll(arr, 1, axis = 0))
#same for y axis
deltaY2 = np.square(np.roll(arr, -1, axis = 1) - np.roll(arr, 1, axis = 1))
#add R, G and B values for each pixel, then add x- and y-shifted values
de_gradient = np.sum(deltaX2, axis = 2) + np.sum(deltaY2, axis = 2)
```

Sample input from [linked reference](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring13/cos226/assignments/seamCarving.html)

```
loaded_pic = np.asarray([[(255, 101, 51), (255, 101, 153), (255, 101, 255)],
                         [(255, 153, 51), (255, 153, 153), (255, 153, 255)],
                         [(255, 203, 51), (255, 204, 153), (255, 205, 255)],
                         [(255, 255, 51), (255, 255, 153), (255, 255, 255)]],
                         dtype = "uint8")
```

Sample output:

```
[[20808 52020 20808]
 [20808 52225 21220]
 [20809 52024 20809]
 [20808 52225 21220]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood your formulas correctly, here's what I would suggest:

```
from scipy.misc import face
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = face() # this is just a sample racoon RGB image for testing

#uncomment to show the racoon image
#plt.imshow(img)
#plt.show(img) # this displays the original image
```

Compute the x-gradient:

```
gradX = np.gradient(img,axis=0)
```

Compute the sum of square of the x-gradient along the RGB components:

```
squareX = np.sum(np.square(gradX),axis=2)
```

Same for y-gradient:

```
gradY = np.gradient(img,axis=1)
squareY = np.sum(np.square(gradY),axis=2)
```

"Dual-energy gradient":

```
dualEnergy = squareX + squareY

#uncomment to display the image
#plt.imshow(dualEnergy)
#plt.show()
```

**Original image**

[image]

**Dual-energy**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @ma3oun I doubt if we are recognizing the mapping from the theory to the implementation correct. I tried it with my images too and they are not similar to what was shown in the reference paper - http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring13/cos226/assignments/seamCarving.html

Comment: `np.gradient` doesn't simply compute the difference of neighbouring array elements. If it did, you would have only integers in `gradX`. But it contains also float values.